# Bluetooth problems on 13.04 (dont see bt-devices)

Tags: 13.04, bluetooth

running Zorin 7 on Ubuntu 13.04 and cant get my BT to work ... it seems that the actual BT device is recognized, but I cant get it to see (or be seen by) other devices

I downloaded Blueman bt manager and Bluez

here some technical info (I'm a Linux newby, so bear with me :-)

```
casa@casa-Inspiron-3421:~$ sudo service bluetooth status
[sudo] password for casa: 
bluetooth start/running, process 1113


casa@casa-Inspiron-3421:~$ bluetoothd -d -n
bluetoothd[27883]: Bluetooth daemon 4.101

bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() parsing main.conf
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() discovto=0
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() pairto=0
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() pageto=8192
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() auto_to=60
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() name=%h-%d
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() class=0x000100
bluetoothd[27883]: src/main.c:parse_config() Key file does not have key 'DeviceID'
**D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.56" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file**
bluetoothd[27883]: Unable to get on D-Bus
bluetooth is unblocked both hard and soft ... looks like  a conflict here ...
```

Any pointers - I don't know what my on board-bt-device is (where would I look it up)?

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding your output:**

Your first command shows that the bluetooth daemon is running. (*bluetooth start/running*) If you want to relaunch the daemon in verbose mode first stop the running daemon (`sudo service bluetooth stop`) then try to launch the daemon with **root privileges** (`sudo bluetoothd -d -n`) because the D-bus policy (`/etc/dbus-1/system.d/bluetooth.conf`) only allows for the root to own the service. (So update your output appropriately.)

But it is likely that if there is a problem with the daemon it would be logged in one of the `/var/log/syslog` files.

**Regarding the problem** ( *I cant get it to see (or be seen by) other devices*):

Did you allow **visibility** in your devices? Like [here](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/09/how-to-set-up-a-bluetooth-connection-in-ubuntu/).